# Optimise large CSV whilst using #group_by & each_with_object

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file with 498,766 rows. The contents of the CSV are pulled remotely and stuffed into a tempfile. Once I have the tempfile I group by a specific column and then go through each of the objects and create a new hash.

```
report = ::RestClient::Request.execute(
  url: report_url,
  method: :get,
  headers: {Authorization: basic_auth.to_s}
)

@file = ::Tempfile.new(["#{report_run.result.filename}", ".csv"])
@file.write(report.body.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
@file.rewind

time = Benchmark.realtime do
  ::CSV.foreach(@file, headers: true)
    .group_by { |fee| fee['charge_id'] }
    .each_with_object({}) { |key, hash| hash[key.first] = key.last.sum { |fee| fee['total_amount'].to_f}.round(2) };
  end
end
```

Benchmarking the above it takes about 52 seconds which seems relatively long to me. Is there any further optimisations that I can make here ?

For added clarity the CSV I'm looking at contains columns: charge_id and total_amount. It is possible for there to be multiple rows with the same charge_id and as such I consolidate them and then sum the total value. A better representation of what the CSV rows would look like is something like:

```
#
# Note this is a dummy representation of CSV data that would come back from 
# doing ::CSV.foreach(@file, headers: true)
#
csv_data = [
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Xt4Kqv3kyKfAnBz9ZJGJ', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Yu4Kqv3kyKfA7CnwoNEo', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79ZQ4Kqv3kyKfAYZMLs8tW', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Ze4Kqv3kyKfAmNbovTjO', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Zs4Kqv3kyKfA38s1yVmq', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79Zy4Kqv3kyKfA99Arn1Lh', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79b04Kqv3kyKfA8uYHL0DY', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79bS4Kqv3kyKfAAWxowFGO', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79dS4Kqv3kyKfADejRhlbZ', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79gM4Kqv3kyKfA30s5NTAj', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79hc4Kqv3kyKfAxJWbu8Ny', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79j64Kqv3kyKfATjAI1JcC', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79jk4Kqv3kyKfAKYdakMAk', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79k64Kqv3kyKfAXmpONrNI', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79le4Kqv3kyKfAJMzltr6U', total_amount: 10.0),
  OpenStruct.new(charge_id: 'ch_1G79lu4Kqv3kyKfAdHG5Qw6r', total_amount: 10.0)
].group_by { |fee| fee['charge_id'] }.each_with_object({}) { |key, hash| hash[key.first] = key.last.sum { |fee| fee['total_amount'].to_f}.round(2) }

#=> 
  {"ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx"=>70.0,
 "ch_1G79Xt4Kqv3kyKfAnBz9ZJGJ"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79Yu4Kqv3kyKfA7CnwoNEo"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79ZQ4Kqv3kyKfAYZMLs8tW"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79Ze4Kqv3kyKfAmNbovTjO"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79Zs4Kqv3kyKfA38s1yVmq"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79Zy4Kqv3kyKfA99Arn1Lh"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79b04Kqv3kyKfA8uYHL0DY"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79bS4Kqv3kyKfAAWxowFGO"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79dS4Kqv3kyKfADejRhlbZ"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79gM4Kqv3kyKfA30s5NTAj"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79hc4Kqv3kyKfAxJWbu8Ny"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79j64Kqv3kyKfATjAI1JcC"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79jk4Kqv3kyKfAKYdakMAk"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79k64Kqv3kyKfAXmpONrNI"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79le4Kqv3kyKfAJMzltr6U"=>10.0,
 "ch_1G79lu4Kqv3kyKfAdHG5Qw6r"=>10.0}
```

Comment: Describe the CSV data, and the problem you're trying to solve with your reduction

Comment: @BillDoughty I updated the question accordingly, hopefully this should give you bit more clarity around what I'm doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more direct way to compute the desired hash from `csv_data` follows. Because it requires a single pass through the array, I expect it will speed things up but have not done a benchmark.

```
require 'ostruct'

csv_data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |os,h|
  h[os[:charge_id]] += os[:total_amount]
end
  #=> {"ch_1G79Pi4Kqv3kyKfABfXoXycx"=>70.0,
  #    "ch_1G79Xt4Kqv3kyKfAnBz9ZJGJ"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79Yu4Kqv3kyKfA7CnwoNEo"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79ZQ4Kqv3kyKfAYZMLs8tW"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79Ze4Kqv3kyKfAmNbovTjO"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79Zs4Kqv3kyKfA38s1yVmq"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79Zy4Kqv3kyKfA99Arn1Lh"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79b04Kqv3kyKfA8uYHL0DY"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79bS4Kqv3kyKfAAWxowFGO"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79dS4Kqv3kyKfADejRhlbZ"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79gM4Kqv3kyKfA30s5NTAj"=>10.0, 
  #    "ch_1G79hc4Kqv3kyKfAxJWbu8Ny"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79j64Kqv3kyKfATjAI1JcC"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79jk4Kqv3kyKfAKYdakMAk"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79k64Kqv3kyKfAXmpONrNI"=>10.0, 
  #    "ch_1G79le4Kqv3kyKfAJMzltr6U"=>10.0,
  #    "ch_1G79lu4Kqv3kyKfAdHG5Qw6r"=>10.0}
```

See the doc for the version of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument called the *default value*.

If the data is received from a remote source a line at a time one could do the processing on the fly, while receiving the data, by writing something like the following.

```
CSV.foreach(@file, headers: true).
    with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |csv,h|
      # <your processing to produce `os`, a line of csv_data>
      h[os[:charge_id]] += os[:total_amount]
    end
```

If this could be done it would have to be benchmarked to see it if actually improved performance.

For readers unfamiliar with this form of `Hash::new`, suppose

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

making `h`'s default value zero. All that means is that if `h` does not have a key `k` `h[k]` returns zero, which I'll write

```
h[k] #=> 0
```

Let's add a key-value pair: `h[:dog] = 1`. Then

```
h #=> { :dog=>1 }
```

and

```
h[:dog] #=> 1
```

Since `h` does not have a key `:cat`

```
h[:cat] #=> 0
```

Suppose now we write

```
h[:dog] += 1
```

That's the same as

```
h[:dog] = h[:dog] + 1
```

which equals

```
h[:dog] = 1 + 1 #=> 2
```

Similarly,

```
h[:cat] += 1
```

means

```
h[:cat] = h[:cat] + 1
        = 0 + 1
        = 1
```

because `h[:cat]` on the right (the method [Hash#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), as contrasted with the method [Hash#[]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) on the left) returns zero. At this point

```
h #=> { :dog=>2, :cat=>1 }
```

When a hash is defined in this way it is sometimes called a *counting hash*. It's effectively the same as

```
h = {}
[1,3,1,2,2].each do |n|
  h[n] = 0 unless h.key?(n)
  h[n] += 1
end
h #=> {1=>2, 3=>1, 2=>2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation surrounding Hash::new() and how effective it can be. I have question regarding the comment: `There is no need to create a temporary file. Just write something like the following.` I do this because the data I'm getting is being access remotely. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: If you are getting something like a zip file then what I suggest would not apply, but if you are getting the remote data a line at a time, and don't need to keep a copy of it after you produce the desired hash, you could do build the hash on the fly. I suspect any benefit would not be significant, however.

Comment: Got it, so the data that I'm getting back isn't a zip. The response body is a string in the format of a CSV. I was initially using `::CSV.parse(report.body.force_encoding("UTF-8"), headers: true)`. What forced me to create a `Tempfile` was switching from `CSV.parse()` →  `CSV.foreach()` because I wanted to to ensure I had performance. That being said in order to use `#foreach` you need to supply a file.

Comment: Re your last sentence, perhaps you could write something `h = {}; open_ remote_connection; loop do; break if no more lines; line = fetch_next_line_remotely; os = f(line); h[os[:charge_id]] += os[:total_amount]; end; h`.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two passes through the data, one to do the grouping (`group_by`) and one to accumulate the sums. Here's an example showing a single pass that does both at once along with your original.  I included benchmarking.

From my tests, the one-pass method is almost 100% faster.  Your mileage may vary.  Also, note that I removed header info when reading the data in my method.  This further reduces processing overhead and memory manipulation.

```rb
require 'csv'
require 'benchmark'

filename = './data.csv'

def one_pass(filename)
  file = File.open(filename, 'r')
  csv = CSV.new(file)

  headers = csv.shift # get rid of headers

  results = Hash.new(0)
  csv.each do |row|
    charge_id, total_amount = row
    results[charge_id] += total_amount.to_f
  end
  file.close
  return results
end

def with_group_by(filename)
  file = File.open(filename, 'r')
  results = CSV.foreach(file, headers: true)
    .group_by { |fee| fee['charge_id'] }
    .each_with_object({}) { |key, hash| hash[key.first] = key.last.sum { |fee| fee['total_amount'].to_f}.round(2) }
  file.close
  return results
end

o_results = nil
g_results = nil

time = Benchmark.realtime do
  o_results = one_pass filename
end
puts "one_pass: #{time}"

time = Benchmark.realtime do
  g_results = with_group_by filename
end
puts "with_group_by: #{time}"

puts "o_results == g_results: #{o_results == g_results}"
```

My benchmarking results with a file that has 56k lines:

```
one_pass: 0.24479200004134327
with_group_by: 0.4725199999520555
o_results == g_results: true
```